# AWS SES Node.js: emails not getting delivered when sent via sendRawEmail

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using `mailcomposer` to create an email with attachments and sending via AWS SES. I am getting successful response after sending the mail. However, the mails never get delivered. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Here is my code:

```
function buildEmail(attachments){
  console.log("attachments", attachments);
  var options = {
    "from": "xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "sender": "xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "to": "xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "subject": "Report Abuse Mail",
    "attachments": []
  }
  var count = 1;
  attachments.images.forEach(function (attachment){
    options.attachments.push({
      "filename": "screenshot_" + count,
      "content": attachment
    })
    count++
  })
  options.attachments.push({
    "filename": "data.zip",
    "content": attachments.data
  })
  var mail = mailcomposer(options);  
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    mail.build(function(err, message){
      if(err) reject(err);
      resolve(message)
    })    
  })
}


function sendEmail(rawData){
  console.log("rawData", rawData);
  var params = {
    RawMessage: { 
      Data: rawData
    },
    Destinations: ['xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'],
    Source: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
  };
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(data);
    });      
  })
}


buildEmail(attachments)
.then(sendEmail)
.then(console.log)
```

Data in the attachments array is like this:

```
{ 
  data: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00 08 00 9d 5a 86  ... >,
  images: [ <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a,
     <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 
  ] 
}
```

And the response I get is like this:

```
{ 
  ResponseMetadata: { 
    RequestId: 'df4aeb16-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-21b92055a5cc' 
  },
  MessageId: '01000153d5865455-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-000000' 
}
```

Comment: If I remove data.zip from attachments and add contentType "image/png" for images attachments, it works fine. But if I include data.zip even after specifying `contentType :"application/zip"`, it does not work

Comment: ok. working now. My zip archive was broken